# Open Dynamics CRM solution with CRM Developer Extensions

Tags: visual-studio, dynamics-crm

I have a solution, developed in **VS2012 with Microsofts CRM toolkit**.
Is there any way to open this in VS2015?

Errormessage:

> Workflow\Workflow.csproj: The application which this project type is
>   based on was not found.

I have installed

> Jason Lattimer's CRM Developer Extensions

and it's great for new projects, but what about my old projects?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. First is to rewrite your old workflows in Jason Lattimers CRM Developer Extensions. Second is to install CRM developer toolkit on VS2015 - it's a bit tricky but not impossible, [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/tsgrdcrmblog/archive/2014/08/23/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-toolkit-with-visual-studio-2013) you can find how to do it for VS2013 but for 2015 is very similar.

Comment: Thanks, pen2
Have You actually tried to patch Micrrosofts toolkit for VS2015? I didn't succeed...

Comment: Yes. I have one installed in VS 2015 right now. In what step you have problem?

Comment: The CRM Developer Toolkit was discontinued, for a reason. It has issues and I would not advise to use it.